# kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig admin.kubeconfig returns "No resources found"

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, unix, devops

I am a newbie in Kubernetes. I am not even very familiar with basic kubernetes commands, but the installation is a starting point for my learning journey. I wanted to avoid installing something like minikube that makes the installation a lot more easy. I was trying to wrap my head around how different components of kubernetes are stitched together to form the overall service. So I was trying to install "Kubernetes the hard way" following this article : https://medium.com/@DrewViles/kubernetes-the-hard-way-on-bare-metal-vms-v1-23-2168f5fe70af

I have completed all the steps till worker pod configuration. At this point I have started getting "No resource found" exception when running the command " kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig admin.kubeconfig" in the controller node.

I am using 1 controller node, 1 lb node and 2 worker nodes. Each of them are VMs with Ubuntu22.04.1 installed. My lab machine is a Windows 11 laptop. Each of the VMs has its own static IP which I configured manually. The standard solution seems to be around correcting KUBERNETES_PUBLIC_ADDRESS in worker node kubeconfig, kube-proxy kubeconfig and kube-apiserver.service. I have already hard-coded KUBERNETES_PUBLIC_ADDRESS to my load balancer static IP address from the very beginning. So, this does not seem to be the issue here.

There are two instructions from the link that I couldn't quite correctly follow. The link states that the file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml has to be updated with static IP. But this file is missing from my VMs. Instead, I have 01-network-manager-all.yaml. I have updated this file and applied the changes.

Another concern for me is that my lab machine doesn't have a public static IP. The worker node certificate creation process, as per the link, involves executing commands with external IP extracted from https://ifconfig.co. I am wondering if these two factors are somehow linked to the issue I am encountering

I appreciate any lead that helps me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that kubectl was trying to connect Kube API server on port 8080 while it was actually running on another port. So I was getting this error :

E1209 01:47:06.243663    1745 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

I fixed it by copying the admin.kubeconfig file to ~/.kube and renaming it to config. I did the same for the worker node by copying the worker node kubeconfig file to ~/.kube and renaming it to config. And the connectivity issue got fixed.

Then I found that the following flags in kubelet.service file under /etc/systemd/system are no longer supported in the last few releases of Kubernetes. I don't know the last kubernetes version for which these flags were supported.

--container-runtime=remote

--image-pull-progress-deadline=2m

--container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock

--network-plugin=cni.

I removed these flags and restarted the kubelet service. The issue got fixed.